# Handling email pop-up prompt using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, popup

I can't figure out how to get around this in Python. The email pop-up is preventing Selenium from clicking on one of the footer links because the pop-up blocks the view of it. I ideally would like to click the "X" and not enter an email.

I've tried using what was in the Selenium documentation about prompts but none of it worked or perhaps I implemented it incorrectly. I tried some of what I already found in stack overflow, which you can see in the commented out code, but kept getting all kinds of errors.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://www.standardmedia.co.ke/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0
##options = Firefox_options();
##options.addPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true)
##driver = webdriver.Firefox(options);

#click on the headings in the footer
for i in range (0,1):
    footer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#top-footer li')[i]
    ##    if(driver.switch_to.alert != null):
    ##        alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    ##        alert.dismiss()
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.dismiss()
        print("Alert dismissed.")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("No alert.")
    footer.click()
    print("alert dismissed")
    page_num += 1
    subheadings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.title a')
len(subheadings)
```

The most recent error for a Firefox web driver was "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebDriver [Alert class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert) is designed to work with JavaScript Alerts to wit:

- [Window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)
- [Window.confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)
- [Window.prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

At the page you're trying to test this modal popup is a normal [`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

[image]

therefore you will not be able to use Alert class, you will have to normally locate close button using [find_element()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function and click it.

1. [Open the page](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get):

   ```
   driver.get("https://www.standardmedia.co.ke/")
   ```
2. [Wait for the popup to appear](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

   ```
   popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mc-closeModal")))
   ```
3. [Click the close button](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click)

   ```
   popup.click()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the selenium connection issue, to address the main question, it looks like you are not calling the `switch_to_alert` function. Once you get selenium connecting, try the following:

```py
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.dismiss()
```

Also note, your wait times are in *seconds* which seem pretty high/long in your code.

Comment: I switched to the Chrome web-driver but am getting that there is no alert after waiting any amount of time. Then I get the error selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException for the click.